# Change SQL Server database context with variable outside SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following situation: I have an installer that installs a web portal on a server and sets up a SQL Server by using a batch file to call a `.sql` file. So far, so good.

Inside that SQL file, I am, among other things, also granting permissions to system accounts in a culture indifferent way. I am relying heavily on variables on this, and that is causing problems.

By now, I have found out a working solution. However, it doesn't strike me as very elegant, since it includes prepending "'USE ' + @database_creation_string " in front of all EXEC statements. The complete relevant context of this script is currently looking something like this:

```
DECLARE @database_name NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @database_name_string NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @user_name_nt_authority_system NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @user_name_nt_authority_system_string NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @database_name = 'fdbn'
SET @database_name_string = QUOTENAME(@database_name)

SET @user_name_nt_authority_system = SUSER_SNAME(0x010100000000000512000000)
SET @user_name_nt_authority_system_string = QUOTENAME(@user_name_nt_authority_system)

EXEC('USE ' + @database_name_string + 'CREATE USER' + @user_name_nt_authority_system_string + 'FOR LOGIN' + @user_name_nt_authority_system_string)
EXEC('USE ' + @database_name_string + 'ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER' + @user_name_nt_authority_system_string)
```

As noted above, this works, but I feel like there has to be a way to actually change the database context so all this prepending isn't possible.

Now I understand that the following doesn't work since all navigation that happens inside an EXEC() statement is ignored outside of that statement.

```
EXEC('USE' + @database_name_string)
```

And I can't use `sqlcmd` mode since I'm calling the script using a `.bat` file.

Is there a more sophisticated  way of doing this? Or is prepending `'USE' + @database_name_string` in front of every `EXEC` statement really the only way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean you can't use `sqlcmd -v` switch? What prevents you from using it?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would to use the sp_executesql after pre-pending the appropriate DB name. A sample would be:
Test.dbo.sp_executesql N'CREATE USER test_user FOR LOGIN [testlogin] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]';

Legend: Test is the DB name

The above statement could be used inside the EXEC after dynamically replacing the required values.